# Android NDK and __android_log_print

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I using this lib: https://github.com/mysolution/hyphenator In JNI I create this function:

```
int main2()
{
 //load russian hyphenation patterns
 struct pattern_list_t* plist = create_pattern_list();
 size_t i = 0;
 while (patterns[i])
 {
 struct pattern_t* p = create_pattern(patterns[i], isdigit_func, ismarker_func, char2digit_func);
 add_patern(plist, p);
 ++i;
 }
 sort_pattern_list(plist);

 //hyphenate test words
 size_t word_index = 0;
 while (test_words[word_index])
 {
 struct word_hyphenation_t* wh = hyphenate_word(test_words[word_index], plist, marker);
 i = 0;
 while (test_words[word_index][i])
 {
   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "HelloNDK!", "%c", test_words[word_index][i]);
 ++i;
 }

 destroy_word_hyphenation(wh);

 ++word_index;
 }

 //cleanup
 destroy_pattern_list(plist);
 return 0;
}
```

In Android NDK this work, but I get in LogCat:

02-21 16:15:18.989: INFO/HelloNDK!(403): �

How to solve this problem? I think that problem in encoding, but i don't know how to solve this.

Comment: I can confirm i get this trying to log out ASCII chars to, i can however log out the myString.c_str(); in a separate call to __android_log_print though so it seems the issue is with the concatenation of the char* , id love to know the fix to this. Will post if i figure it out.

Comment: You appear to have a type mismatch, but without declaration of `test_words` I can't tell. The compiler should be able though (gcc has special support for printf format types); turn on warnings.

Answer (score 0):

What is your expected output? If the character falls outside the realm of ASCII you'll of course need to have something to view logcat that supports it. Assuming you're outputting UTF-8, [Terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/) is nice on Linux and [Mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) (In combination with Cygwin/etc.) on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, and this seems very wrong to me.....

So for char* concatenation in __android_log_vprint and __android_log_print it would appear you need to use the escape %s not %c.

This totally scuppers my plans for making a cross platform char* log between iOS, Android and Blackberry as printf("%s",myString.c_str()); is illegal. Will have to get funky with the args and parse the string. Anyway that's another problem and there is your fix ....

Comment: `printf("%s", myString.c_str());` is _legal_ and the only correct method. "%s" expects `const char *` and that's what `c_str()` method (if it's `std::string::c_str()` or has matching signature) returns. Temporaries exist until end of _statement_, so long enough for the printf to work on it.